# Firestore database access with Openui5 (like JSON model or OData model))

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, sapui5

I am using a firestore database for my Openui5 app. The data binding to the controls is very difficult and I have to manually get and set controls data using DOM elements.
Using OData/JSON model with  Openui5 it will be easy to bind the data to the controls just using the REST URL in the manifest  file and binding the corresponding attributes to the controls.  is it possible to convert the firestore data into JSON model and use this REST service in the Openui5 app? It seems the firestore REST API can be used only in the server side to manage the firestore database by admins. But I want to use the REST API in the mobile app itself.

## askFirebase .

Answer (score 0):

Firestone API already provides data as JSON. For example, use the URL

```
https://demo.firebaseio.com/users.json?
```

You just need to add .json in the end.

With that, it should be pretty easy to load data into the JSON model.

Comment: Hi @Krisho, Thanks for your information. Yes, this is possible in the firebase real time data base. but i want to use this method in the cloud firestore data base. i tried to access the firestore data base using the Cloud Firestore REST API. but this works only with OAuth 2.0 authentication on on Google developer console. Example i used this link https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject/databases/(default)/documents/Users in the developer console with firestore REST API  and i am able to see the data in the json format. But i want to use the same link in my app.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var myConfig = {
                    apiKey: "AIza**************************E",
                    authDomain: "k*****s.firebaseapp.com",
                    databaseURL: "https://******s.firebaseio.com",
                    projectId: "k******s",
                    storageBucket: "",
                    messagingSenderId: "7*******"
                  };

        this.myApp  = firebase.initializeApp(myConfig,  '_name');
        this.myDB   = this.myApp.firestore();
        this.myDB.collection("myCollection").doc(key).onSnapshot(function(doc){
                var aDocs = [];
                aDocs.unshift(doc.data());
                that.MyTable.getModel().setProperty('/items', aDocs);
            });
```

Firestore stores data like json and returns data as json. I used here onSnapshot event. If a new data is created, that function runs. You can set `doc.data()` value to a json or bind a model.